# Dynamic component throwing render function or template not defined in component error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

In my Nuxt application wanted to render components dynamically in `<component>` based on the route parameters, but doing that I'm getting below error:

> render function or template not defined in component: anonymous

#### _calculator.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="px-4 py-5 py-sm-80 px-sm-128">
      <component :is="calc"></component>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>

import { calculators } from '../../store/constants';

export default {
  components: {
    ...
    'sip-calculator': () => import('../../components/calculators/sip-calculator.vue'),
    'cagr-calculator': () => import('../../components/calculators/CagrCalculator.vue'),
    'ppf-calculator': () => import('../../components/calculators/ppf-calculator.vue'),
    'swp-calculator': () => import('../../components/calculators/swp-calculator.vue'),
  },
  async asyncData({ params: { calculator } }) {
    const activeCalculator = calculators.find(c => c.slug === calculator);
    console.log(activeCalculator.component, 'activeCalculator.components');
    const calc = await import(`../../components/calculators/${activeCalculator.component}.vue`);
    

    return {
      activeCalculator,
      inactiveCalculators,
      calc
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getCalculators() {
      return calculators;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

#### constant.js

```
export const calculators = [
  {
    slug: 'sip',
    component: 'sip-calculator'
  },
  ... for other calculators also
]
```